# Rsync and wildcards

Tags: backup, rsync, regex, chrome

I am trying to back up both the "Last Session" and "Current Session" files for Google Chrome in one command, but using a wildcard doesn't seem to work.

I am trying with the following command

```
rsync -e "ssh -i new.key" -r --verbose -tz --stats --progress --delete '/cygdrive/c/Users/jay/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/*Session'   user@host:"/chrome\ sessions/"
```

and get the following error

```
rsync: link_stat "/cygdrive/c/Users/jay/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/*Session" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Cygwin is at home and I'm at the office, but you should make sure that the spaces in your directory names are properly escaped with a backslash when using the double-quotes for the wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the ' quote means that the * won't be used for expansion.

```
Try rsync -e "ssh -i new.key" -r --verbose -tz --stats --progress --delete "/cygdrive/c/Users/jay/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/*Session"   user@host:"/chrome\ sessions/"
```